# Nesting StackNavigator inside BottomTabNavigator react-navigation v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Going through my first React Native project, using react-navigation v5, and struggling to work out the logic behind multiple navigators in one.

I've tried to copy the ['auth-flow'](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow) setup from here, but I have some extra requirements, where once signed in, it should render a bottomTab navigator with three items (create, lists, account) where the second screen lists, renders a list of items where clicking one opens a new screen for the details (where I'd imagine these two screens would be a stack?)

```
pseudo routes:
- home
- lists 
    - details  <- nested in the tab navigator screen
- account
```

current setup:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
          {isSignedIn ? (
              <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name='List' component={TrackListScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name='Create' component={TrackCreateScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name='Account' component={AccountScreen} /> 
              </Tab.Navigator>
          ) : (
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name='Signup' component={SignupScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name='Signin' component={SigninScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll want to do is make the `List` tab it's own stack navigator. So you'll have this

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {isSignedIn ? (
          <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='TrackListNavigator'>
            <Tab.Screen name='TrackListNavigator' component={TrackListNavigator} />
            <Tab.Screen name='Create' component={TrackCreateScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name='Account' component={AccountScreen} /> 
          </Tab.Navigator>
         ) : (
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name='Signup' component={SignupScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name='Signin' component={SigninScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

So then instead of the tab navigating to `TrackListScreen`, it instead navigates to a new stack navigator that contains that screen like this

```
export default function TrackListNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='TrackListScreen'>
      <Stack.Screen name='TrackListScreen' component={TrackListScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

This way, when you are not signed in you will only have access to the `Signup` and `Signin` screens. Then once signed in you will land on the `TrackListScreen` with access to any other `Stack.Screen` you add to the `TrackListNavigator`.

Comment: I had a similar set to this - though in reverse, and auth routes as the StackNavigator (TrackListNavigator) and the home route would render the TabNavigator. This is working better. Thank you!

Comment: Hey Al, with this setup, how would I navigate back to a sign in route from the account screen - as there will be a logout button that clears the token and should be re-directed back.

Comment: @joshuaaron I used context, and provided a stateful variable and it's setter through context. So then when a user signs out I use the context setter `setIsSignedIn(false)`. The variable is updated and the user is kicked back to the SignUp screen

Answer (score 1):

You would in this scenario create an extra holding component, such as TrackListHome. TrackListHome would be a component that is specifically a StackNavigator, with the initialRouteName being your TrackListScreen, and Details would be another Screen in your StackNavigator. Then you would be able to call

```
props.navigation.navigate("TrackListDetail")
```

Your StackNavigator might look like this (TrackListHome)

```
return (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={'TrackListScreen'}>
    <Stack.Screen name='TrackListScreen' component={TrackListScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name='TrackListDetail' component={TrackListDetail} />
  </Stack.Navigator>)
```

Then inside of your TabNavigation you would use this TrackListHome component.